# Issue with wordpress search result pages lists

Tags: wordpress, search

I am facing problem while searching in wordpress.
I have used `<?php get_search_form(); ?>`for making search bar and put it in our header file so that anybody can search through this.

But whenever we are trying to search using any keywords through this search box, we will get proper result for posts only(**image**, **excerpt** and with **continue reading** button), But our pages will not able to show proper excerpt instead it will taking some code related to that page with **continue reading** button.

Below is the link for your reference,

https://www.ttademo.timesandtrendsacademy.com/?s=course

And also tell us, Is it a right way to add search box in our website, If it yes, then how do i design the search box with proper look.

Thanks

Comment: Please check my answer.

Comment: You have manage search box in right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove read more by below css:

```
.search-introtext .read_more {
    display: none;
}
```

Hope this works for you.

Comment: But i don't want to remove read more, just have issue with page result short description will take as a page code instead of short description. Refer: https://www.ttademo.timesandtrendsacademy.com/?s=fashion

Comment: Open search.php  find the_excerpt() and replace with the_content()

Comment: the_excerpt() is not their in themes search.php file

Comment: can you please provide me search.php code so i can check and help you.

Comment: And you want to display full content in search page after searching?

Comment: I just want to show our search result short description as some content but it will showing some code type content (this issue only with pages search result), as per above reference URL, Otherwise works proper.

Comment: See first three search result excerpt in this URL:https://www.ttademo.timesandtrendsacademy.com/?s=fashion

Comment: ok got your questions, page searching break your div so it will display code like this.

Comment: @Gopal: You can add short description from back-end and display in search result, this is the only solutions for your questions.

Comment: Yes, got it, those pages have less content and only have sections with visual-composer, That's why it will show like this.

Comment: One more doubt, How can we make a proper design for the same search box with search icon and all.

Comment: We can manage search design with search icon also, with custom code customize.

Comment: Here is one issue, We have pages, posts and also have course pages. But when we search in above case this will only gives us pages and posts result only. How we can also get course pages also in the search result.